# Zip 2 lists of Observable with different return types

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I'd like to wait until all the data from the API to be downloaded successfully and then do some operations on it.

The data result from observablesAPI1 and observablesAPI2 are different.

```
    val observablesAPI1:List<Single<ApiResponse1>? = idApi1List.map{api1Repository.getData(it)}
    val observablesAPI2:List<Single<ApiResponse2>? = idApi2List.map{api2Repository.getData(it)}

    // this is not working
    Single.zip(observablesAPI1,observablesAPI2,BiFunction <List<ApiResponse1>, List<ApiResponse2>> { apiResultList1, apiResultList2 -> // operations}
```

I thought about using nested zips but I'm not sure if it's possible to do that.

Edit:
 
There is actually 2 errors
when hover on observablesAPI1(similiar error on observablesAPI2):

> Type missmatch. Required: SingleSource!>!
>   Found: List>?

when hover on BiFunction:

> 3 type arguments expected for fun
>   BiFunction(function:(t1: T1, t2: T2) ->R):BiFunction))

Comment: why is not working? could you please be more specific - which error you are getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to suggest you change the way which you map ids to data.

```
val observablesAPI1 = Observable.fromIterable(idApi1List)
    .flatMapSingle { id -> api1Repository.getData(id) }
    .toList()

val observablesAPI2 = Observable.fromIterable(idApi2List)
    .flatMapSingle { id -> api2Repository.getData(id) }
    .toList()

Single.zip(observablesAPI1, observablesAPI2, BiFunction<List<ApiResponse1>, List<ApiResponse2>, String> { list1, list2 ->
    //do something
}).subscribe()
```

Note, that in my solution in `zip` function you have just two easy maintainable lists of `ApiResponse1` and `ApiResponse2`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are having compilation errors.

This is from the javadocs of [BiFunction](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/3.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/rxjava3/functions/BiFunction.java):

```
/**
 * A functional interface (callback) that computes a value based on multiple input values.
 * @param <T1> the first value type
 * @param <T2> the second value type
 * @param <R> the result type
 */
public interface BiFunction<T1, T2, R> {
```

Your observablesAPI1 and observablesAPI2 have the type `List<Single<ApiResponse*>` but you are writing `List<ApiResponse*>`.

You are also missing the result type. For example, if you want to return a String, this is how your code should look like:

```
Single.zip(
    observablesAPI1, 
    observablesAPI2,
    BiFunction<List<Single<ApiResponse1>, List<Single<ApiResponse2>, String> {
        apiResultList1, apiResultList2 -> "my result!"
})
```

Comment: I try your approach (slightly different because i assume you forgot to close bracket in the single) and now ive got only the type mismatch errors "Type mismatch. Required: SingleSource <out List<Single<ApiResponse1>>!>! Found: List<Single<ApiResponse1>>?"

Comment: This is because your observablesAPI1 and observablesAPI2 return a `List` instead of a `Single<List>`. You should change them to return `Single<List<Single<ApiResponse*>>>`.

Comment: but int the end Id like to make operations for the List<ApiReposnse1> and List<ApiResponse2> objects

Comment: then change your observablesAPI* to return a a `Single<List<ApiResponse*>>`. Inside the BiFunction their types will be `List<ApiResponse*>`

Comment: In order to do the above, check @Andrei Tanana's answer below